# Give me an example of an algebra that cannot be extended to a sigma algebra through finite/countable process of taking unions/intersections?

Tags: measure-theory

I've heard that finite or even countable process of taking unions/intersections can't make a collection of sets a sigma algebra.

That is, if $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(M)$ is an algebra, and $\mathcal{\bar{A}} = \{A: \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A_i = A \text{ or } \bigcap_{i=0}^\infty A_i = A \text{ for some }A_i \in \mathcal{A}\}$, then the followings are NOT true in general:

1. $\mathcal{\bar{A}} = \sigma(\mathcal{A})$
2. Let $\mathcal{A_0} = \mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{A_1} = \mathcal{\bar{A_0}}$, $\mathcal{A_2} = \mathcal{\bar{A_1}}$, ..., then $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty\mathcal{A_i} = \sigma(\mathcal{A})$

However, I couldn't think of any counter-example. 
Could you please give me some counter-examples of 1 and 2?

Comment: The Borel sets on the real line, as generated by the open sets of the line, provide the canonical example. Your procedure essentially climbs the Borel hierarchy up to level $\omega$ (the first infinite ordinal). But the Borel hierarchy for the line extends up to level $\omega_1$ (the first *uncountable* ordinal).

Comment: Basically, the procedure looks like this. Perform your "completion" step countably many times, getting collections of subsets $\mathcal{A}_n$ for each $n=1,2,\dots$. Then you combine them all by taking an infinite union, getting $\mathcal{A}=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{A}_n$. But now I can pick a set $B_n \in \mathcal{A}_n$ for each $n$ and consider $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n$. In the real line, this can produce a set which is not in $\mathcal{A}$, which means $\mathcal{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Ian Thanks. Is there any text or link that describes about it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Generating_the_Borel_algebra shows that everything "stops" at $\omega_1$, though I'm not finding anything simple that says that $\omega_1$ steps are *required*. The name of the field that studies this sort of thing is descriptive set theory, try looking for that.